# Quantum circuit that puts qubits in "equal" superposition

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer

I would like to build a circuit that takes multiple qubit system states and puts them in a superposition with equal amplitudes.

For example:
Let's consider a 4 qubit system. I would like the circuit to start with an input of $\left| 0000 \right>$ and end with the following superposition: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{4}}\left(\left| 1000 \right> + \left| 1010 \right> + \left| 1001 \right> + \left| 1100 \right>\right).$$

I would like for the choice of states and number of states to be arbitrary. I.e. that I can easily perform the same circuit to generate

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left(\left| 1000 \right> + \left| 1011 \right> + \left| 1101 \right>\right),$$

or

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\left| 1000 \right> + \left| 1010 \right> + \left| 1001 \right> + \left| 1100 \right> + \left| 1111 \right>\right).$$

Can anyone help me with this? Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: I have tried creating a matrix representation of such an operator, and I have found one that does what I need it to do, it maps the $\left|00\right>$ to an arbitrary equally-distributed superposition of the basis vectors of my choosing. Here is the matrix I found that acts on 2 qubits to create such a state:

$$
U = \begin{pmatrix}
1/\sqrt{3} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1/\sqrt{3} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1/\sqrt{3} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

This gives:

$$
U\left|00\right>= \begin{pmatrix}
1/\sqrt{3} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1/\sqrt{3} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1/\sqrt{3} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix} =
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left( \left|00\right> + \left|01\right> + \left|10\right> \right).
$$

The idea is that the first column of the matrix would consist of $N$ non-zero elements, each element contrbuting one basis state to the final superposition, and each element being equal to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$.

The problem with this matrix, however, is that it is not unitary. Would it be possible to modify this matrix in such a wat that it still has the same result on the $|00>$ state vector, but that it *is* unitary? This would solve my problem completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a few hints:

- To produce equally distributed superposition containing all combinations of $n$ qubits, simply put Hadamard gate on all qubit.
- Bell states and GHZ states belong among states your are talking about. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenberger%E2%80%93Horne%E2%80%93Zeilinger_state) is a circuit how to produce GHZ states (see also article below)
- You might also be interested in W states, i.e. equally distributed superposition of bit strings where only one qubit is in state 1 and others are zero. In article
  [Efficient quantum algorithms for GHZ and W states, and implementation on the IBM quantum computer](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.05572) an algorithm how to produce such states is described.

---

**EDIT:**

Concerning the matrix, it is possible to construct the matrix for example in this way:

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 &-1 \\
1 & -1 & 1 &0 \\
1 & 0 & -1 &1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 &1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The matrix is unitary (you can check this by a direct multiplication) and  the required state is returned for input $|00\rangle$. You do not have to bother about other inputs because you can always set all input qubits to state $|0\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Those are some good suggestions. What do you think of the edit I made to my question?

Comment: @CarloJacobs: Please find an idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot! How did you come up with that matrix so fast? Is there some sort of technique?

Comment: And if there is, can I generalise that technique for bigger matrices or matrices with a different first column?

Comment: @CarloJacobs You don't care what the outputs of $U$ are for $\left|01\right>, \left|10\right>, \left|11\right>$ so you can just choose them to be any three states that are orthogonal to $U\left|00\right>$ and to each other.

Comment: @gandalf61 Thanks! That worked.

Comment: @CarloJacobs: The easiest way is to have a unit matrix, then change the first column so that it contained the desired quantum state and then use so-called Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization process (see Wiki). It leaves the first column intact and ensure that the matrix is unitary.